# Why file_put_contents() not always rewrites a file?

Tags: php

I wonder, why PHP `file_put_contents()` function works in a weird way.

I used it in a loop to write some logs to file and all was fine (new lines were appended even if no flag was specified). When I started the script again, it re-created my file.

*From PHP doc:*

> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the
>   existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

OK, so my question is: Why (when used in one loop) it doesn't overwrite my file (without FILE_APPEND flag of course)? Bug or feature? :)

Edit: Example context of use when this happened:

```
$logFile = dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/example.log';
foreach($something1 as $sth1) {
    $logData .= "Something\n";
    foreach($something2 as $sth2) {
        if($something_else) {
            $logData .= "Line: \t" . $sth2 . "\n";
            file_put_contents($logFile, $logData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php]..this should help

Comment: If it doesn't overwrite the file, then what does it do? Show a working demo of code, and explain what you expect and what you're actually getting

Comment: It works that way.. When you set the file_append it would just go on appending one after another. Most common example would be the php error logs which is created. But when you set it off the file content changes every time you do it.

Comment: Problem is I used it in a wrong way and it worked as I wanted [created my log file with multi  lines!]. Then I restarted script and file was recreated. Manual said thaf tile should be recreated every time with no flag. that's the problem, why in one loop this function appends new lines with no flags.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been very clearly mentioned in [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) under the flags content(which you should have read) it clearly states that if file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it(when this flag is set). So when the flag for FILE_APPEND is set it appends and when not it rewrites. Hope this helped you.

Comment: Problem is I used it in a wrong way and it worked as I wanted [created my log file with multi lines even thoug it should NOT!]. Then I restarted script and file was recreated [correct behavior]. Manual said thaf tile should be recreated every time with no flag. That's the problem, why in one loop this function appends new lines with no flags.

Comment: @garbus.. sorry i couldn't recreate your scenario. because the one i used did work fine as documented.

Comment: Thank you @preeti-maurya for this info. I will try to recreate this in a simple working code. If it will get the same results, I will paste it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Way

```
 <?php

        $file = 'file.txt';

        $append = true;

        if (file_exists($file)) {

            if ($append) {
                // append file
                $file = fopen($file, 'a+');
            } else {
                // overwrite file
                $file = fopen($file, 'a');
            }

        } else {

            // create file

            $file = fopen($file, 'a');

        }

        fwrite($file, 'text');

        fclose($file);

    ?>
```

here is a [php fopen documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

and [php file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

and read on its related topics

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the code. I know how to fix it. My question is rather why this happened...

Answer (score -1):

ok, when you are run the script each time try to rename the log file with `random number or currentdate timestamp` and try to save it in your DB 
by this when you again run the script and can take the log file name from DB and update it when you needed

Comment: That's not what he asked for.